# Elasticsearch filter term is not working?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to get a very basic filtered query to work with Elasticsearch.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "name": "stanford designs"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: which version do you use?

Comment: Please post your index mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's strange as your query seems fine, but might be possible you are using some older version of Elastics.
You can use the bool must before term filter as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "name": "stanford designs"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this would work.